# Multiple devices getting same text messages

Tags: itunes, iphone

I am part of a company where a lot of people use iPhones/iPads.  I don't personally and never have, so I'm at a loss here and am hoping someone here can tell me.

We have a company iTunes account set up, it makes it easier when setting up iPhones and iPads to have one account set up so we don't have to buy apps multiple times and I don't have to make up an iTunes account for every single employee and remember all the information for each one.  2 people in my company I know have the same iTunes accounts on their phones, and they're both getting messages meant for the other one.  Is this because of the iTunes account being the same?  Is the iTunes account somehow tied to the text messaging capability of iPhones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, they will probably be getting the same iMessages due to the same iTunes account being used and being the default for iCloud.

What you could do is go to `Settings > iCloud` and change or create a personal iCloud account for the person.  In `Settings > App and iTunes Stores`, the original email you used for apps should stay there.

Or just turn off iMessage so the phones default to SMS. This can be done in `Settings > Messages`.

Comment: If I turn off iMessage, this won't mess with receiving text messages?

Comment: Yeah, it won't. But make sure that `Send as SMS` is enabled on every phone in `Settings > Messages`. Edit: actually 'Send as SMS' is hidden when you turn off iMessage, so you should be fine.